# How to sort students by age in data structure

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort students by age.

I did so far was sorting just the age without the full data (name, grade, etc).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct students {
    char l_name[30];
    char f_name[30];
    int age;
    int grade;
    float height;
};

students student[100];

void sort_age() 
{
    int aux[100], i;
    sort(student.age, student.age + nr_students); //I know this is wrong.. 

    cout << "Showing students..." << endl;
    if (nr_students == 0) 
    {
        cout << "No students registred!" << endl;
        cout << "Select option ""'4'"" to register some students!" << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_students; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student: "<<student[i].l_name << " ";
        cout << student[i].f_name << ", ";
        cout << "Age: "<<student[i].age << " y.o, ";
        cout << "Height: "<<student[i].height << "cm, ";
        cout << "Grade: "<<student[i].grade << " grade" <<endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I expect the students to be sorted by age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to write a compare function and then let the built-in sort function know to sort the array according to function.

```
   students student[100];
    bool cmp(students A, students B) {
         return A.age < B.age;
    }
    // inside of sort_age() function
    sort(student, student + nr_students, cmp);
```

Comment: You should pass objects by const reference, it is not a good idea to copy 2 them on every comparison.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. So the compare function should be:
bool cmp(const students A, const students B) {
         return A.age < B.age;
    }

Comment: @FarukHossain Then you still copy 2 objects on each comparison. `bool cmp(const students& A, const students& B) { ... } ` avoids such copies as @Yksisarvinen answered.

Answer (score 2):

Standard library comes to your aid with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

```
std::sort(student, student + nr_students, [](const auto& s1, const auto& s2){
        return s1.age < s2.age; });
```

*Note:* Generic lambdas (with `auto` as parameter type) are a feature of C++14. If you specify lambda as `[](const students& s1, const students& s2){/*body*/}`, it will work with C++11 standard, or you can use a function pointer like in Faruk's answer for pre-C++11 compiler.

---

You could also provide overload for `operator <` to your class, but it may not always be the case that you want to sort them by age. It could be very confusing then.

```
bool operator< (const students& s1, const students& s2) 
{
    return s1.age < s2.age;
}
```

---

As a side note, you should use `std::vector`. It would handle holding number of elements for you and it can resize itself to your needs.
Also, why did you name your class `students` and the array of 100 `students`s is called `student`?

Comment: You probably should mention that your solution requires c++14 or later